# Please generate dataset that will display the PreAssemblyQty and BomLevel that have PreAssemblyQty less than or equal to 8.00 (adventureworks 2016)

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

Please generate dataset that will display the PreAssemblyQty
and BomLevel that have PreAssemblyQty less than or equal to 8.00

```
SELECT PreAssemblyQty, BomLevel
FROM YourTableName -- Replace YourTableName with the actual name of your table
WHERE PreAssemblyQty <= 8.00;
```

help me find the table name

Answer (score 0):

With

```
USE AdventureWorks2016;  
GO  
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME,
COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'BomLevel';  
GO
```

You find your table

[image]